# How to decrypt a dumped android partition on a pc?

Tags: root-access, linux, disk-encryption, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

I chose to boot android on the from the sdcard in order to have more storage. So I dumped though `dd` the internal 32Gb storage to the 256Gb sdcard with the partition table included. By just changing the kernel command line and the `ro.boot.bootdevice` property, the device now boots from the sd card after loading the kernel from the internal storage.

- I then put the sd card in a pc, fixed the partition table size to match the one of the sd and then set up the userdata partition `(/data)` to fill the remaining space.
- Then I wiped the filesystem and performed a factory reset in order to hope it would create a 250Gb filesystem for `/data`. But [while `data` was mounted from the sd card and that the mapped block device was 250Gb large](https://superuser.com/a/1537505/282033), it was formated using 25Gb instead of 250GB (the original size on internal storage).

This means I have to grow the `/data` filesystem using an external computer. Now the question is, what’s the exact `dmsetup` command in order to create the block device for decrypting it for growing the ext4 filesystem using `resize2fs`?
Given also I forgot which is the file containing the decryption key.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106184/discussion-on-question-by-user2284570-how-to-decrypt-a-dumped-android-partition).